# MySQL group concat used with 2 join table query results duplicate

Tags: php, mysql, group-concat

I have joined 2 tables and use group concat to get data on some coloumns. below is my query. this returns same row twice

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(  vehicles.role ORDER BY vehicles.id ASC SEPARATOR '\n') as role,GROUP_CONCAT(  vehicles.size ORDER BY vehicles.id ASC SEPARATOR '\n') as size,festivals.id,festivals.ref_no as ref_no, festivals.camping,festivals.tour_mgr_name,festivals.email,festivals.mobile,festivals.name_address, GROUP_CONCAT( namedesgs.name  ORDER BY namedesgs.id ASC SEPARATOR '\n') as names,GROUP_CONCAT( namedesgs.designation  ORDER BY namedesgs.id ASC SEPARATOR '\n') as designations
FROM festivals
    LEFT JOIN namedesgs  ON festivals.id = namedesgs.festival
    LEFT JOIN vehicles  ON festivals.id = vehicles.festival 
Group BY festivals.id
```

please advice how to get data without duplicates?

when i used DISTINCT with concat . it does not work for below

ex:

namedesg data

[image]

vehicles data

[image]

current output

[image]

but on my output veicles data has duplicates 3 times even though one data exist.

here is query i tried

```
SELECT t.id, GROUP_CONCAT(a.name SEPARATOR '\n') as name,
 GROUP_CONCAT(a.designation SEPARATOR '\n') as desg ,GROUP_CONCAT(b.role SEPARATOR '\n') as role,
 GROUP_CONCAT(b.size SEPARATOR '\n') as size
FROM festivals t
 LEFT JOIN namedesgs a ON a.festival=t.id 
 LEFT JOIN vehicles b ON b.festival=t.id  
where t.id=4
GROUP BY t.id


festivals

id ref_no
1   AAA
2   BBB
3   CCC

namedesgs  

id name designation festival(festival table id)
1  ann   SE              1
2  ben   AE              1
3  Jan   cook            1
4  alun  cook            1
5  hej    hik            2
6  nij    AE             1

vehicles

id role size   festival(festival table id)
1  r1   14              1
2  r1   12              1
3  r2   12              1
4  r3  12              1
5  r4    12            2
```

what i want as out put is

```
festivalid name designations role  size
1           ann    SE          r1  14
            ben    AE          r1  12
           jan    cook         r2  12
           alun    cook        r3  12
           aij    AE          
2          hej    hik         r4   12
```

Comment: Use `DISTINCT` in `GROUP_CONCAT` to remove duplicates.

Comment: @Barmar : I used it too GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT vehicles.size ORDER BY vehicles.id ASC SEPARATOR '\n' but when data has duplicate then it removes that also. see the attached image of my table. when i used DISTINCT it will return only on 'desg6' even thought there are two in table. pls advice

Comment: @Barmar : pls check the updated part of my question.

Comment: Can you show sample data and the desired result?

Comment: @Barmar please check my question i added info. pls help

Comment: What is the output you're trying to get instead? Also, it would be better if you posted the data as plain text, so we can copy and paste it when testing.

Comment: @Barmar kindly check now. i added in plain text

Comment: I don't understand your desired results. Why is `ben AE` on the same row as `r1 12` and not `r1 14` or `r2 12`?

Comment: @Barmar : because i want to show all the names -designations and size -roles for a specific festival id in one row. that's why i used group concat . but with joins its duplicating data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you want, you can't put `name` and `designation`, and `role` and `size`, in separate columns in the results. You need to concatenate them before using `GROUP_CONCAT`. And use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicates.

```
SELECT t.id AS festivalid, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(a.name, ' ', a.designation) SEPARATOR '\n') AS `name designations`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(b.role, ' ', b.size) SEPARATOR '\n') AS `role size`
FROM festivals AS t
LEFT JOIN namedesgs a ON a.festival=t.id 
LEFT JOIN vehicles b ON b.festival=t.id
GROUP BY t.id
```

Comment: still duplicating . same as my 'current output' image

Comment: See my question above. I don't understand how you're relating rows from the `namedesgs` and `vehicles` table to get them on the same row of results.